# Adding information from one JsonBuilder object to another

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

As the title suggests, I'm trying to add information held in one JsonBuilder object to a second JsonBuilder object.

Currently I have this:

```
public String buildOneUser(DyveUserDTO user)
{
    def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
        userBuilder user.collect { usr ->
            [
                    'Name': usr.userName,
                    'Allowance': usr.allowance,
                    'Total Holidays in Calendar': usr.totalHolidaysInCal,
                    'Holidays Booked': usr.numHolidaysBooked,
                    'Holidays Taken': usr.numHolidaysTaken,
                    'Holidays Remaining': usr.totalHolidaysLeft
            ]
        }

    def userHolidayBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
        userHolidayBuilder user.holidayEvents.collect { usr ->
            [
                    'Start Date': usr.startDate,
                    'End Date': usr.endDate,
                    'Days': usr.days
            ]
        }

    def userAndHolidays = userBuilder + userHolidayBuilder

    return userAndHolidays.toPrettyString()
}
```

`user.holidayEvents` is a list of objects representing holidays and it could be empty or have any number of objects in it. This made me hesitant of doing something like:

```
def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
        userBuilder user.collect { usr ->
            [
                    'Name': usr.userName,
                    'Allowance': usr.allowance,
                    'Total Holidays in Calendar': usr.totalHolidaysInCal,
                    'Holidays Booked': usr.numHolidaysBooked,
                    'Holidays Taken': usr.numHolidaysTaken,
                    'Holidays Remaining': usr.totalHolidaysLeft
                    'Holiday': usr.holidayEvents[0].startDate
                    'Holiday': usr.holidayEvents[0].endDate
                    'Holiday': usr.holidayEvents[0].days
            ]
        }
```

As I would only get the amount of holidays I write code for. It would also throw an exception if a user had no holidays and I told it look at `usr.holidayEvents[1]` as it's outside of the list range.

I've also tried nesting a `.collect` like this

```
def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
        userBuilder {
           'Name' user.userName,
           'Allowance' user.allowance,
           'Total Holidays in Calendar' user.totalHolidaysInCal,
           'Holidays Booked' user.numHolidaysBooked,
           'Holidays Taken' user.numHolidaysTaken,
           'Holidays Remaining' user.totalHolidaysLeft,
           'Holidays' user.holidayEvents.collect{ evt ->
               [
                  'Start Date': evt.startDate,
                  'End Date': evt.endDate,
                  'Days': evt.days
               ]
            }
        }
```

But this returned all the keys except the Holidays key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - My code now looks like this:

```
public String buildOneUser(DyveUserDTO user)
{
    def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
        userBuilder user.collect { usr ->
            [
                    'Name': usr.userName,
                    'Allowance': usr.allowance,
                    'Total Holidays in Calendar': usr.totalHolidaysInCal,
                    'Holidays Booked': usr.numHolidaysBooked,
                    'Holidays Taken': usr.numHolidaysTaken,
                    'Holidays Remaining': usr.totalHolidaysLeft,
                    'Holidays': usr.holidayEvents.collect{ evt ->
                        [
                                'Start Date': evt.startDate,
                                'End Date': evt.endDate,
                                'Days': evt.days
                        ]
                    }
            ]
        }
}
```

EDIT 2 - Sample Code

Method to call:

```
public String buildOneUser(DyveUserDTO user)
{
    def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    userBuilder {
        Name:
        user.userName
        Allowance:
        user.allowance
        TotalHolidaysInCalendar:
        user.totalHolidaysInCal
        HolidaysBooked:
        user.numHolidaysBooked
        HolidaysTaken:
        user.numHolidaysTaken
        HolidaysRemaining:
        user.totalHolidaysLeft
        Holidays:
        user.holidayEvents.collect { evt ->
            [
                    'Start Date': evt.startDate,
                    'End Date'  : evt.endDate,
                    'Days'      : evt.days
            ]
        }
    }

    return userBuilder.toPrettyString()
}
```

User to pass in:

```
class DyveUserDTO
{
    String firstName = "Foo"
    String userName = "FooBar"
    Integer userID = 42
    BigDecimal numHolidaysBooked = 3
    BigDecimal numHolidaysTaken = 0
    BigDecimal totalHolidaysInCal = 3
    BigDecimal totalHolidaysLeft = 12
    BigDecimal allowance = 12
    List<HolidayObject> holidayEvents = []
```

}

Holiday objects to go in holidayEvents:

```
class HolidayObject
{
    public Integer userID = 42
    public String title = "Foo Holiday"
    public String event = "Holiday"
    public String amPm = "Full Day"
    public String name = "Foo"
    public LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(2015-02-20T00:00:00)
    public LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(2015-02-20T00:00:00)
    public BigDecimal days = 1
}

class HolidayObject
{
    public Integer userID = 42
    public String title = "Foo Holiday Pm"
    public String event = "Holiday"
    public String amPm = "Pm"
    public String name = "Foo"
    public LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(2015-02-23T00:00:00)
    public LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(2015-02-24T00:00:00)
    public BigDecimal days = 2
}
```

Comment: in your last code example, the each is "wrong" (it just returns usr.holidayEvents).  you would have to use the same `collect` as in the first example instead (collect and return maps)

Comment: Sorry @cfrick, have provided my answer at the same time.

Comment: Changed the last block of code, I've used .collect but it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Opal - Your code definitely does work, but It doesn't seem to want to play nice with mine. Could passing in the already built user affect this?

Comment: *passing in the already built user* - don't understand?

Comment: In my first block of code I'm calling this inside a method, to which I'm passing a user object

Comment: @Opal - I've updated the question to show my current code

Comment: There's no need to call `collect` on a single instance of user.

Comment: I've edited the code but in the wrong place unfortunately do You see the difference? It should work now.

Comment: @Supergoat21, let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @Opal - I think I caught your edit, I tried to edit over the top at the same time! Unfortunately it still doesn't work just prints out empty curly braces.

Comment: @Supergoat21, could You please provide a full sample that I could try with?

Comment: @Opal - Added sample code to the question. Is that what you were after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` just returns the list it's called upon, `collect` should be used for `events`. See the working code below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class UserEvent {
    def start
    def end
    def days
}

class User {
    def name
    def events
}

def u1 = new User(name: 'u1', events: [new UserEvent(start: 0, end: 1, days: 1), new UserEvent(start: 0, end: 2, days: 2)])
def u2 = new User(name: 'u2', events: [new UserEvent(start: 0, end: 3, days: 3)])

def users = [u1, u2]

def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
userBuilder users.collect { usr ->
   [
      'name': usr.name,   
      'events': usr.events.collect { e ->
         [
            start: e.start,
            end: e.end,
            days: e.days,
         ]
       }                   
    ]
}

print  userBuilder.toPrettyString()
```

**EDIT**

Below is a working example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

user = new DyveUserDTO()

def userBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    userBuilder {
        Name user.userName
        Allowance user.allowance
        TotalHolidaysInCalendar user.totalHolidaysInCal
        HolidaysBooked user.numHolidaysBooked
        HolidaysTaken user.numHolidaysTaken
        HolidaysRemaining user.totalHolidaysLeft
        Holidays user.holidayEvents.collect { evt ->
            [
                    'Start Date': evt.startDate,
                    'End Date'  : evt.endDate,
                    'Days'      : evt.days
            ]
        }
    }

println userBuilder.toPrettyString()

class DyveUserDTO {
    String firstName = "Foo"
    String userName = "FooBar"
    Integer userID = 42
    BigDecimal numHolidaysBooked = 3
    BigDecimal numHolidaysTaken = 0
    BigDecimal totalHolidaysInCal = 3
    BigDecimal totalHolidaysLeft = 12
    BigDecimal allowance = 12
    List<HolidayObject> holidayEvents = [new HolidayObject(), new HolidayObject()]
}

class HolidayObject {
    public Integer userID = 42
    public String title = "Foo Holiday"
    public String event = "Holiday"
    public String amPm = "Full Day"
    public String name = "Foo"
    public String startDate = '2015-02-20T00:00:00'
    public String endDate = '2015-02-20T00:00:00'
    public BigDecimal days = 1
}
```

No colons `:` needed. See the sample [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html). Also I have no Joda dependency so replaced with String.

Comment: I've removed the colons but it's still not picking up the Holidays key. I feel this probably warrants a new question rather than discussing it here. I'll accept your answer as it DOES work, I've tested it independently of my code, it just won't work with my code. Thanks anyway!